# Do various substitutions but only before a character

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I am doing something like this:

```
echo 'foo_bar_baz=foo_bar_baz' | sed -r 's/_([[:alnum:]])/\U\1/g'
```

and getting as result:

```
fooBarBaz=fooBarBaz
```

Is there a way of getting `fooBarBaz=foo_bar_baz` instead?

I tryed to do this, non-greedy:

```
echo 'foo_bar_baz=foo_bar_baz' | sed -r 's/([^=].*?)_([[:alnum:]])/\1\U\2/g'
```

but the result is this:

```
foo_bar_baz=foo_barBaz
```

What I need is to convert from:

```
foo_bar_baz=foo_bar_baz
```

to:

```
fooBarBaz=foo_bar_baz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
s='foo_bar_baz=foo_bar_baz'
sed -E ':a;s/^([^=_]*)_([[:alnum:]])/\1\U\2/g; ta' <<< "$s"
# => fooBarBaz=foo_bar_baz
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/O2qTC6)

**Details**

- `:a` - define an `a` label to jump to if the substitution is a success
- `s/^([^=_]*)_([[:alnum:]])/\1\U\2/g` - find

  - `^` - start of string
  - `([^=_]*)` - Group 1 (`\1` in the replacement pattern): any 0+ chars other than `=` and `_`
  - `_` - an underscore
  - `([[:alnum:]])` - Group 2 (`\2` in the replacement pattern): an alphanumeric char
  - `\1\U\2` - Group 1 value and then an uppercased Group 2 value
- `ta` - `t` is a branch command making sed go back to the `a` label and repeat matching.

Answer (score 5):

***EDIT:*** Adding more Generic solution which will work for more than 3 values before `=` too.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="="
}
{
  num=split($1,array,"_")
  for(i=2;i<=num;i++){
    val=(val?val:"")toupper(substr(array[i],1,1)) substr(array[i],2)
  }
  $1=array[1] val
  val=""
}
1
'  Input_file
```

---

---

This should be an easy task for `awk`.

```
echo 'foo_bar_baz=foo_bar_baz' | awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="="
}
{
  split($1,array,"_")
  $1=array[1] toupper(substr(array[2],1,1)) substr(array[2],2) toupper(substr(array[3],1,1)) substr(array[3],2)
}
1'
```

---

---

To simply remove `_` in first part use(this will not make letter capital):

```
echo 'foo_bar_baz=foo_bar_baz' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}{gsub(/_/,"",$1)} 1'
```

Comment: That is a clever solution.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Thank you sir, you made my day :)

Comment: DOWN VOTER, please do mention the reason for down vote?

Comment: @Fábio Roberto Teodoro, could you please check 1st answer and let me know if this helps you(not sure if you have wrongly down voted my answer :))?

Comment: This answer solves the problem as I presented it, so I didn't downvoted it. But it only works for three words, as was my example, while my chosen answer works for any number of snakecase words, because of this I didn't upvoted this too.

Comment: @FábioRobertoTeodoro, Why I asked you about downvote because the time you chosen correct in this post I got down vote, BTW down vote means button near to thread when we hit it downwards(in case you are new on SO). Also I prepared solution as per your samples, please do let me know how your real data looks like?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, My real problem is to get a bunch of environment variables which might be in snakecase and convert its names to camelcase, without changing its values, to pass as arguments for a mvn proccess.

Comment: @FábioRobertoTeodoro, Please check my EDIT solution and let me know then? That should work for any Number of `_`before `=`

Comment: @FábioRobertoTeodoro, Did my solution worked for you correctly now? I see an edit to it.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 yes :)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'h;s/_(.)/\u\1/g;G;s/=.*=/=/' file
```

Make a copy of the current line. Remove all `_`'s and uppercase the following characters. Append the copy and replace everything between `=`'s with a single `=`.

An alternative:

```
sed -E ':a;s/_(.*=)/\u\1/;ta' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ echo 'foo_bar_baz=foo_bar_baz' |
  awk '{while (match($0,/(.*)_(.)(.*=.*)/,a)) $0 = a[1] toupper(a[2]) a[3]} 1'
fooBarBaz=foo_bar_baz
```

Note that the above solution is not restricted to any specific number of `_`s nor any specific letter following the underscores:

```
$ echo 'wee_sleekit_cowrin_timrous_beastie=foo_bar_baz' |
  awk '{while (match($0,/(.*)_(.)(.*=.*)/,a)) $0 = a[1] toupper(a[2]) a[3]} 1'
weeSleekitCowrinTimrousBeastie=foo_bar_baz
```

Change `_(.)` to `_([[:lower:]])` if you only want the underscores removed when followed by a lower case letter.